# Property 'className' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'IProps'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to pass some classes to child.

For some reason it seems like props are not passing down.

I have parent component:

```
import React from "react";
import Logo from "./Logo";
import SidebarMenu from "./SidebarMenu";

interface IProps {
  className: string;
}

function Sidebar(props: IProps) {
  return (
    <aside className={`h-screen bg-gray-200 ${props.className}`}>
      <div className="my-4">
        <Logo className="w-0" />
      </div>

      <div className="my-4">
        <SidebarMenu />
      </div>
    </aside>
  );
}


export default Sidebar;
```

And the child Logo component:

```
import React from "react";
import logo from "../assets/images/logo.png";

interface IProps {
  className: string;
}

function Logo(props: IProps) {
  return (
    <img
      src={logo}
      alt="project vdora logo"
      className={`rounded max-w-full ${props.className}`}
    />
  );
}

export default Logo;
```

And I get this **error:**

```
TypeScript error in .../src/components/Login.tsx(63,16):
Property 'className' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'IProps'.  TS2741

    61 |           <Card className="p-4 bg-green-900">
    62 |             <div className="mb-4">
  > 63 |               <Logo />
       |                ^
    64 |             </div>
```

**Solutions tried:**

I tried to make the `className` optional, then it's working.

If baffles me because I did exactly the same method in Grandparent component and it works normally.

Why is not passing? How to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `Logo` component, you have mentioned the props type as `IProps` and className is required field there. You are doing properly for `Sidebar` component but not for `Login` component. (where you are getting the error `TypeScript error in .../src/components/Login.tsx(63,16):`)

```
<Logo className="w-0" />
```

Comment: yes, I had <Logo> in Login component too. Ive made className in Logo optionas > className?:string, for anyone reading this